# Colors are washed out on new monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, colors

I recently bought a second monitor for my laptop but the colors are all washed out and black is grey. This makes reading text on wite background difficult.

It's a PHILIPS 223V5LHSB2/00
Led 
21.5 inch 
1920 x 1080 pixels, Full HD (1080p)

I've seen many reviews saying that the colors are washed out and some said they solved it but not how they did it.

Using windows 10 home, 64 bit
Graphic card is GeForce GTX 765M

I've read about changing NVIDIA consol panel but I don't get the options presented that are in the guides.

Here is what it looks like for me (in Dutch)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the brightness and contrast settings on the monitor itself?  Also, just to note, it looks like your monitors are connected to the Intel HD 4600 GPU instead of the GeForce GTX 765M GPU from your screen shot.  That may be why you don't have the nVidia options you have seen in the guides.